# Jax-Rs can't find Path on Request

Tags: java, rest, maven, jax-rs, httprequest

I trying to write a simple HelloWorld REST Service with Jax-Rs.
I tried many tutorials but everytime I get the same error.

This time I followed this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qez0ynuo61w

I am using a simple Maven Project.

This is my Project Structure:
[image: Project Structure]

My pom.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.moritz</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxrsbasic</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>jaxrsbasic</name>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.containers/jersey-container-servlet -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId>
      <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.core/jersey-server -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>2.31</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.inject/jersey-hk2 -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
      <version>2.31</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jersey.media/jersey-media-json-jackson -->
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>2.31</version>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>jakarta.activation</groupId>
          <artifactId>jakarta.activation-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.11</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>

  <build>
    <finalName>jaxrsbasic</finalName>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>${maven.compiler.source}</source>
          <target>${maven.compiler.target}</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>

      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>9.4.29.v20200521</version>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

My web.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
             http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>REST Service Basic</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.comfig.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>org.moritz</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>REST Service Basic</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

My App.java

```html
package org.moritz;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

@Path("/rest")
public class App {

    @GET
    @Path("/sayhi")
    public Response sayHi() {
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity("Hello World!").build();
    }

}
```

To start my Application I used the following commands in the command line:

1. mvn clean install
2. mvn jetty:run

Now when I call

> localhost:8080/api/rest/sayhi

I get this

[image: Error]

Any suggestions what I can do? I tried this the last days and I have no Idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You have a typo here `jersey.comfig.server.provider.packages` (comfig)

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! It works... I was about getting crazy.